# "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)" in Django dev env using https without valid certificate

Tags: django, csrf

Pretty sure this is the reason I'm getting the `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)` error in my development environment:

- Working on Azure AD authentication
- URI Redirects require either `localhost` or `https://`
- Since I'm developing in a local `k8s` cluster with `skaffold`, it has an `minikube ip` like `192.168.64.7`
- Thus, I'm having to do `https://192.168.64.7/` for my URI redirects and not using a valid SSL certificate since I'm just in dev
- I'm at the point where I'm sending the `accessToken` from the React FE to the our API for it to be validated again there
- Pretty sure Django is seeing `https://` and that it is not valid causing this error

So my questions are:

- Am I correct about why this error is coming up?
- Is there a setting I can enable in development to ignore this?
- Or is my only option to get a valid SSL certificate for my dev environment?

I have verified that doing the following does not work:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [

    '*'
]
```

Also, `GET` requests are working but `POST` are not.

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
class TestView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

```
// Authentication.js

  const testApiAuthentication = async () => {
    let accessToken = await authProvider.getAccessToken();
    setAccessToken(accessToken.accessToken);
    if (accessToken) {
      setAuthenticatingToken(true);
      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/users/',
        headers: {
           Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

---

EDIT:

One option (**and not a good one**) is to the following to exempt it from CSRF.

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class TestView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

Again, not a good idea to do this...

I did manage to implement a certificate for my dev environment thinking it would resolve the issue, but it still persists.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was I needed to be using `django-rest-framework` since, from what I read, it has the CSRF exemption built in. I thought I'd use Django views to quickly test this, but that turned out to be causing the issue. **Need to use DRF.**

### Below is for reference just incase it helps anyone with `@csrf_exempt` on class-based views or implementing TLS in a local development k8s cluster.

As I pointed out, one option (**and not a good one**) is to the following to exempt it from CSRF.

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# Create your views here.
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class TestView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

The TLS implementation that worked for me was the following (largely based off of [this blog article](https://itnext.io/deploying-tls-certificates-for-local-development-and-production-using-kubernetes-cert-manager-9ab46abdd569)):

1. Decide the DNS name you want to give your app and add it to `/etc/hosts` and map it to `minikube ip` (yes, unfortunately, you will have to keep this updated if you do a `minikube delete`). In my case it was:

```
192.168.64.7      companyapp.local
```

Then refresh your local DNS. On macOS it was:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

2. Update your dev `ingress-nginx.yaml` to use `hosts`. I wasn't doing this originally in my dev ingress. I ended up with:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/admin)$ $1/ permanent;
  name: ingress-service-dev
  namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - companyapp.local
      secretName: tls-companyapp-dev
  rules:
    - host: companyapp.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /admin/
            backend:
              serviceName: admin-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 4000
          - path: /api/
            backend:
              serviceName: api-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 5000
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service-dev
              servicePort: 3000
```

3. Install [`mkcert`](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) and generate the certificates (see link for your OS):

```
brew install mkcert
brew install nss # if you use Firefox

mkcert -install

mkcert companyapp.local
```

4. Install [`cert-manager`](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/):

```
# Kubernetes 1.16+
$ kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.0.4/cert-manager.yaml

# Kubernetes <1.16
$ kubectl apply --validate=false -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.0.4/cert-manager-legacy.yaml
```

Wait until the Pods are ready checking with:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
```

5. Make a k8s secret entry with the certificates from `mkcert`:

```
kubectl create secret tls tls-companyapp-dev --key=companyapp.local-key.pem --cert=companyapp.local.pem
```

You should be able to delete the `.pem` files after doing this.

6. Make the `Issuer` and `Certificate` manifests and apply them:

```
# issuer.yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-dev-issuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  ca:
    secretName: tls-companyapp-dev
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-dev-certificate
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: tls-companyapp-dev
  dnsNames:
    - companyapp.local
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-dev-issuer
    kind: Issuer
```

And apply them with:

```
kubectl apply -f <manifest_location>/issuer.yaml
```

It took a couple tries, but eventually I was able to navigate to `companyapp.local` and it had a valid certificate. Don't have to deal with "Unsafe" messages anymore.

**All that being said... It still didn't fix my issue.**